# How to initialize a vector in the constructor of a class

Tags: c++, constructor, vector, initialization

How could I initialize a two dimensional vector in the contstructor of a class with zero values? This won't work:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class matrix {
 public:
  typedef int element_type;
  matrix(int dim):data(dim, vector<int>(dim, 0)) {
  }
 private:
  vector<vector<element_type>> data;
};
```

Do I have to write a destructor to free the vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** OP's code is now valid from C++11 onward.

**Original answer for earlier versions of C++:**

---

You need to write it like this:

```
vector< vector<element_type> > data;
```

because `>>` is otherwise parsed as stream operator, which is invalid here. And: No, you do not need to free this in the destructor, because you aren't creating it on the heap.

Comment: C++0x should fix this annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to write a destructor to free the vector?

No, because you did not acquire any resources in the constructor. That's the beauty of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).